# how is it possible to assign println() method into a variable

Tags: scala

I started learning Scala only a day ago, now I'm testing a few random codes to see how it behaves. I find it a quite interesting programming language, especially  for its SCALAbility.

Any way, while trying some code, I "accidentally" ran this:

```
var myVal =  println("test") 
println(myVal)
```

and I was surprised that it runs successfully without any errors, and the output was simply:

> test
>   ()

so I tried to find out what  data type was given to this variable

```
println(myVal.getClass)
```

and it was

> void

What I understood is that, as we all know, the `println()` method returns void which is logically **nothing** and cannot be assigned, but I guess it's possible in Scala to do so (even though there is no type for variables called void).

So, if I suppose this is possible, I must have nothing into my variable, it must be empty, because it is void, why do I have `()` as output? and what will be the type `myVal`?

Comment: Welcome to the Scala community, first of all, please please please don't use variables ( I know you are just fiddling but figured I would mention)  ```var``` in Scala is eager, and println() is one big effect in Scala, thus it return ```Unit``` , not ```void```. ```()``` is a short hand for ```Unit```. The ```void``` part comes from ```getClass```. My guess is that getClass can't find the class and falls back on Java's ```void``` (possibly because of the type erasure)

Comment: Thus you can also do ```val x : Unit = println("test")```

Comment: @sinanspd why you said "please don't use variables" ? and what do you mean by `var` in Scala is eager? thanks

Comment: mutation is bad for many reasons, can't fit them in a comment but plenty of resources out there on this that you can read. You will also find, they don't play well with many frameworks and libraries in the Scala ecosystem. The latter means, it evaluates immediately, even if you don't use it (as opposed to lazy values)

Comment: May I ask how are you learning Scala? Any decent tutorial / book / course have to tell you two important things. First, that `vars` should be avoided, specially unnecessary ones. Second, that every expression in Scala returns a value. - PS: Scala is not another OOP language, learning syntax is not enough, you need to learn a new paradigm.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez actually, mainly I am following this tutorial https://www.tutorialspoint.com/scala/index.htm and I am taking a look at other sources at the same time

Comment: @Bashir yeah, seems like worst tutorial I have ever seen. It is also pretty outdated. On the **Scala reddit** there have been a couple of recent post about good books and tutorial for learning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`println("test")` is an expression in Scala just like any other expression which means it evaluates to a value of particular type. `println("test")` returns a value `()` of type [`Unit`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Unit.html). The value `()` might look a bit unusual initially, but it is nevertheless just a regular value. Consider the following

```
val x: Int = 42
val u: Unit = ()
```

The type `Unit` does not carry much semantic value. It tells us a side-effect was executed, but does not pin down exactly what kind of side-effect it was. Imagine compiler desugars definition of

```
def println(x: Any): Unit = Console.println(x)
```

to something like

```
def println(x: Any): Unit = {
  Console.println(x) // execute side-effect
  return ()          // return value
}
```

Note the `return ()`.